# Autohotkey script - FileCopy not working consistently when doing a backup to dropbox

Tags: autohotkey, file-copying

My code works inconsistently, though it has a high success rate.

What it does is that it saves the ahk file and automatically make a backup of it in my dropbox folder. However, the inconsistent part is that **sometimes the backup is not done in the dropbox folder**. How should I change my script to make sure that the backup is done 100% of the time? Thanks!

My code below:

```
RCtrl:: 
SaveMyFile()
CloseAhk()                  ; to backup ahk file in dropbox & close editor
Return


SaveMyFile() {              ; to save the ahk file and reload it
WinGetActiveTitle, Reload
  If InStr(Reload, ".ahk") {   ; to check if it is ahk file
     MsgBox, , , to_run.ahk is reloaded, 0.6
     Send ^s                
     Reload
  }
  Else
     Send ^s
}

CloseAhk() {                
IfWinActive, to_run.ahk - Notepad
{
     FileAhkBackup()        ; calls the backup function
     WinClose               ; to close the ahk file
}
}

FileAhkBackup() {           ; the backup function
FileCopy, C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\to_run.ahk, C:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\AHK\, 1
}
```

Thanks once again :)

Comment: Why don't you simply create a [hard link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) for your script file?

Comment: I suppose that can be a workaround, however, I would like to understand why it does not work as it should.

Comment: One reason could be that you copy the file before it is saved by Notepad. I don't know how exactly Notepad handles a save operation, but I think it just rewrites the whole file. Copying a file that suddenly gets overwritten sounds like a bad idea. Try waiting for the save operation to finish. Checking the [last modification time](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileGetTime.htm) in a loop might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing a few sleep 1000s in there and make sure that you are not trying to send a process before the previous one is complete.